# " Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details" at eb deploy

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just update my local pip ver to 21 and then I resolved dependencies conflicts.
Just after this when I run `eb deploy` it showed error

```
Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

My requirements.txt
(Stack overflow claims post is mostly code if I use code block thus I had to limit list to only part of entire list)

```
Django==2.0.4
awsebcli==3.19.2
docker==4.2.0
firebase-admin==4.4.0
google-api-core==1.23.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
six==1.15.0
social-auth-app-django==3.1.0
social-auth-core==3.2.0
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what exactly is your `requirements.txt`? What exactlly version of Eb are you using?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I added part of requirements.txt (could not paste all since stack overflow claims there are too much code on question)

Comment: Put your requirements.txt on gist then -- if it's more than that can handle, you need to reexamine your architecture

Comment: Log says ```You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 21.1.1 is available.``` this probably is a main cause